# Is Netty ChannelHandlerContext.set/getAttachment() thread safe?

Tags: netty

It has been suggested that one way to store stateful information across invocations of a handler is by using setAttachment() and getAttachment() methods in the ChannelHandlerContext object attached with the handler. But I don't see any synchronization around setting/getting the attachment in the implementaiton classes of ChannelHandlerContext. In that case, how could one possibly ensure the visibility of the attachment across invocations of a handler object, e.g. across multiple calls to messageReceived() on the same handler object, when these calls are presumably invoked in different threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachment itself is volatile, so yeah it is thread-safe:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/channel/DefaultChannelPipeline.java#L715